# Aligning Icons vertically in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm having trouble aligning the Icons of the Elementor Icon List widget vertically in Wordpress.

Everything is great if I use one of the Font Awesome icons from the Icon Library. However, if I upload an SVG icon myself instead of using one from the Icon Library the vertical alignment of the icon gets messed up. Please refer to the image below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAomb.jpg

The first icon is one of the Font Awesome icons from the Icon Library and the other 2 icons are uploaded by me. As you can see the first icon is vertically aligned perfectly in the middle while the 2 icons uploaded by me are not.

Is it possible to vertically align the 2 icons in the middle using custom CSS?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
.elementor-icon-list-icon {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without seeing your HTML, we are guessing. Please post the HTML for the section in your screen shot along with any CSS styling that section. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).